# How to integrate live streaming of local FM/AM radio station

Tags: wordpress, live-streaming, internet-radio

How can I setup a live streaming of fm/am local radio station on WordPress. I'm using WordPress to power a radio station website and one of the core feature is to have a live streaming of the radio station programs (fm/am) but couldn't see any plugin out of the box that can do this. Hence, I need expert tip on how to go about solving this.

Thank you in anticipation.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find the live stream URL of your local FM/AM radio station. For example, the Houston public media has its live stream located at:

http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/kuhf/ppr/kuhfnews_128.m3u

Next step is install a WP plugin like [Background Music Player Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/background-music-player-lite/). You are all set!

Comment: Thanks,I will share the experience when I'm through.